# Setting up a framework-only SilverStripe site

Tags: silverstripe

I'm looking to create a framework only SilverStripe website, however I have been unable to correctly set up the routing for it.

I want to have a single controller handling a handful of URLs. I want it to handle an empty URL too, i.e. `'/'`.

I've been unable to get my controller to differentiate between the different urls.

My routes are as follows:

```
---
Name: rootroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    '$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'MainController'
    '': 'MainController'
```

and my controller:

```
class MainController extends Controller {

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' => 'handleAction',
    );

    public function index() {
        return "index";
    }

    public function login() {
        return "login";
    }

    public function handleAction($request, $action) {
        var_dump($action); // always 'index'

        if($this->hasMethod($action)) {
            return $this->$action();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the $allowed_actions array on your controller before actions other than index() will work.